# how to save a file in the correct encoding?

Tags: c++, c++builder

when you save the file, the Unicode characters are stored as character encoding

```
TMemoryStream *MS = new  TMemoryStream;
TStringList *list = new TStringList;
list->Add(u"call=expose_full");
IdHTTP1->Post(u"URL", list, MS);
MS->SaveToFile("1.html");
```

For example "Atl\u00e9tico Rafaela Stats"

Comment: Don't forget to specify what kind of unicode you are using, IE: UTF-16 for windows, UTF-8 for most other systems. ETC.

Comment: from the site from which downloading is specified: content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "TmemoryStream" class, you may want to specify what API it comes from - However does it have the option to save the file using "binary" output (similar to fstream)?

Comment: Save it as a file written for example, I need to get the text from the website and then parse it

Comment: Assuming it is UTF-8, saving it as binary will still render a plain-text readable file, however it won't attempt to convert to ASCII (which standard text-mode does).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a version of `Post()` that writes the server's raw data as-is to a `TStream`. `TMemoryStream` is just a memory buffer, it has no concept of strings, characters, or encodings.  You are saving the HTML file exactly as the server sends it. Whether it is using UTF-8, UTF-16, Ansi, whatever.

If you want to save the file in a specific encoding of your choosing, you have to convert the data yourself after downloading it. For instance, by using the version of `Post()` that returns a `String` instead of filling a `TStream`, then you can use a `TStringList` or `TStringString`, or the `System::Ioutils::TFile::WriteAllText()` method, to save the `String` to a file using a specific `TEncoding` such as `TEncoding::UTF8`.

Or, if the server supports it, you can use the `TIdHTTP::Request::AcceptCharSet` property to specify which charset you are willing to accept from the server, and then the server can encode its response accordingly. Then you can continue using your original code shown above.